# How to disable Xcode 4 console line wrap?

Tags: xcode

I am trying to disable line wrapping in my log output, but I cannot find the option

How can I disable line wrapping in Xcode console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible (as of Xcode 4.6). Please file a bug at [radar.apple.com](https://bugreport.apple.com/).